# Blank page and the code 403 on view

Tags: python, django, permissions, http-status-code-403, django-guardian

I want to add permissions for users who are in the Employee group that in order to be able to see the view, but do not add. When I go to view with decorator I get a blank page and the code 403.
I use django-guardian.

**MODEL**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, help_text=_('Please enter name'))
    date_from = models.DateField(help_text=_('Please specify start date'))
    date_to = models.DateField(help_text=_('Please specify end date'))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('MyModel')
        verbose_name_plural = _('MyModels')
        permissions = (
            ('can_view', _('Can view')),
            ('can_add', _('Can add')),
        )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.free_day_type
```

**VIEW**

```
class Add(CreateView):
    template_name = "myapp/add.html"
    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyModelInputForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('myapp:add')

    @method_decorator(permission_required_or_403('myapp.can_view'))
    @method_decorator(permission_required_or_403('myapp.can_add_holidays'))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(Add, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

**ADMIN**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import MyModel
from guardian.admin import GuardedModelAdmin


class MyModelAdmin(GuardedModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Comment: What's the definition of the view class that users are trying to view a ```MyModel```?

Comment: @schillingt there is a form

Comment: I meant that you should add the code to the question. You have something blocking the view that handles the GET request. We need to see what that view is.